# Android Espresso 3.0 Accessibility check

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have installed new Android 3.0 and trying to add accessibility checks to my tests. 
According to the documentation here https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/accessibility-checking.html one is supposed to add the `@BeforeClass` annotation and everything will be great.
The thing is that when I run the tests now with `AccessibilityChecks.enable();` I get "Empty test suite" when I actually have tests there and they are running correctly when I do not have this `AccessibilityChecks.enable()` included.
Somebody experienced the same behaviour?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue.  I am using 3.0.1 and Kotlin.  I created a companion object (static method) and only get the error "Empty test suite" when i try running the tests with it included.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue.  When I switched to deprecated:
`AccessibilityChecks` from `import android.support.test.espresso.contrib.AccessibilityChecks;` my tests's started and it's showed accessibility errors.

I know that's not the long-term solution...

Comment: you found any solution for this ??